# image doesn't show after adding new path

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to replace an image on a page after uploading a new one with carrierwave and jquery-file-upload-rails. The problem I'm having is that the new image doesn't actually show on the page even though the element's html is properly replacing the old image's html tags.

The image is properly being saved, and the paths match.

Here's my update.js

```
<% if @logo %>
  $('.logo-container').replaceWith("<div class='logo-container'><img href='<%= @logo.image_url %>' class='col-1 col'/></div>");
<% end %>
```

I'm thinking this may be a cache issue but I'm not yet certain.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was using href and not src. Meh!!

Answer (score 3):

if you are using jquery you can just change the patch of src using this:

```
$(".logo-container").attr('src',image_url);
```

Comment: I was hoping this would work. Instead of replacing the image with the new url it seems to replace it with the old one and adds /?livereload=somerandomnum to it. Maybe the Live Reload is messing it up? If I just type the correct path manually the image still doesn't show. Even though it's in the correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try first emptying the container?

`<% if @logo %>
  $('.logo-container').html('').html("<div class='logo-container'><img href='<%= @logo.image_url %>' class='col-1 col'/></div>");
<% end %>`